# Hashmap with specific key type but any value type in function parameters

Tags: java

Is there a clean way to take in a hashmap as a function parameter with a specific key type, but any value type?

E.g. I have a few hashmaps with Integer as the key but each uses a different object for the values and I want to create a function they can share. I was thinking something like this but it won't allow me to pass my hashmaps in as they have a more specific value type than Object

```
public static int getUnusedId(Map<Integer, Object> map){
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow.same way which you have specified.

Comment: getUnusedId(Map<Integer, ?> map)

Comment: I am unable to pass in a hashmap created like so however "HashMap<Integer, MyObject> map"

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet that was perfect. Can you post it as an answer so I can approve?

Comment: OP, you're looking for generics. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html Since I stupidly can't post an answer since the question was closed, I'll put it into a comment: public static <T> int getUnusedId(final Map<Integer, T> map) {} public static void main(final String[] args) { final Map<Integer,String> map = new HashMap<>(); System.err.println(getUnusedId(map));}